# Subsonic 2.2 Source code

Tags: subsonic

Where is the source code for subsonic 2.2? I can see the binary version of 2.2 but not the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't [this it](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/source/browse/#svn/branches/Release_2.2)?

Comment: Thanks, it is - did not see that. There used be a zip file with the source code in for previous releases. I suppose I will have to pull it down using a svn client.

Comment: It can't hurt to pull the current revision (522) from trunk because it contains some bugfixes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562488/where-to-find-subsonic-2-2-source-code) the latest version is [here](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/) on github (despite nothing suggesting it's 2.2 instead of say 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found, Its a open source so you can download from here.
http://subsonictools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets