# Where to find SubSonic 2.2 Source Code?

Tags: subsonic

I'm a bit confused on where to find the most up-to-date copy of SubSonic 2.x, after following the links I think it's here: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0 on GitHub, but I don't see anything showing it's 2.2+ versus something lower like 2.0 or 2.1.  Can somebody confirm that GitHub has the most up-to-date version of SubSonic 2.x, I just want to make sure I'm tweaking the latest version of 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, github has the latest version of the version 2 source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link where you can download subsonic version 2 till 2.2.

https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/downloads